# Quartz still blocked job when lost connection with db

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler, quartz

I'm using Quartz in Spring Boot. The issue arises when there's a loss of connection to the database during job execution. Upon restoring the database connection, the trigger remains in the database with a status of BLOCKED. At that point, restarting the application is necessary to unblock the job or manually change trigger status in the database.

Is it possible to configure Quartz to wait for the database connection to be restored?

Comment: I found the problem that causes this error. In my application, job status changes are saved to the database using JobListener. When there is no connection to the database, the listener throws an error that stops the job execution. After handling the exception in listener, the job continues to execute after restoring the connection to the database.